# Yii2 - Setting Mailer Transport parameters on runtime

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to set the configuration for the Mailer, for example in basic template `config/web.php` i have added below.

```
$config = [
    'components' => [
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'testmailhost.com', // want to replace with $mail_host
                'username' => 'test@test.com',
                'password' => 'testing111',
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'tls'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Now I want to set the values for host, username, password port etc stored in database table settings. so how can replace these values here.

I have created a component which I can access the values as

```
$st = Yii::$app->getTable;
$mail_host = $st->settings('general', 'mail_host');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Yii2 Mailer class provides you with a public method named [`setTransport`](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer/doc/api/2.1/yii-swiftmailer-mailer#setTransport()-detail) to which you can pass the transport config array as param.

In the config just add the mailer component configurations and add the `transport` configurations via your custom component.

```
$config = [
    'components' => [
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'useFileTransport' => false,
        ]
    ]
];
```

See the below code, you can use it in your component now to add the transport configurations from your database.

```
Yii::$app->mailer->setTransport(
        [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'localhost', 
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
            'port' => '587', 
            'encryption' => 'tls'
        ]
    );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: so you mean in my component I can add the above code snippet and use - for example 'username' => $username, - am I right?

Comment: also can I do it for other parameters as well - for example I want to include paypal info like - 'client_id' => 'YOUR-CLIENT-ID-FROM-PAYPAL',
    'client_secret' => 'YOUR-CLIENT-SECRET-FROM-PAYPAL', but you stated that yii2 mailer class provides public method `setTransport`. so how I can achieve this for such as these parameters?

Comment: @Joshi the Mailer class has nothing to do with the Paypal credentials, the answer above is for the Mailer component, if you have another question add a new one, and yes you can use the above snippet as is by copy pasting just change the `username` and `password` that are coming from the database

Comment: Thanks you so much Omer for your help. I will add another question for paypal.

Comment: Hi Omer I have added another question for paypal parameter - link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711056/yii2-setting-value-in-config-from-component-or-database-2 - Please take a look, how it can be resolved.

Comment: @Joshi i added an answer to your question

Comment: Hi Reborn/Omer - can you take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/67034320/1124993