# Update swiftmailer configuration based on user input

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer, yii2-basic-app

I need to update SwiftMailer configuration based on user input, particularly, the user may decide to send emails using SMTP protocol or store them locally (in an specific filesystem's folder). The user will use a view to decide the option, then the controller catch the decision and update a session var. The current approach is to read that session var from config/web.php and then choose the appropriate configuration.

I am not sure whether web.php is loaded just once during the application execution, in fact I can not check if the session is active and then get the info from the var. I'm not sure what approach may be the appropriate one.

This is my config/web.php:

```php
<?php
use yii\web\Session;

$params = require __DIR__ . '/params.php';
$db = require __DIR__ . '/db.php';
$session = Yii::$app->session;
if($session->isActive){
    $mailTransport = Yii::app()->session->get('emailtransport');    
}
else{ //session is not started
    $mailTransport = 'local';
}

if($mailTransport=='local'){
    $config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'a4ARdWYauHJ-UEAvVfagzk0LTyT_KEuZ',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@app/mail',
            'htmlLayout' => 'layouts/main-html', //template to Send Emails Html based
            'textLayout' => 'layouts/main-text', //template to Send Emails text based
            'messageConfig' => [
               'charset' => 'UTF-8',
               'from' => ['clients@ok.com' => 'OK Premiun Clients'],
             ], //end of messageConfig
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
            //'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'ok@gmail.com',
            'password' => "password",
            'port' => '465',
            'encryption' => 'ssl',
          ],
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => $db,
        /*
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
        */
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
}//end of if loop
else{
    $config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'a4ARdWYauHJ-UEAvVfagzk0LTyT_KEuZ',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@app/mail',
            'htmlLayout' => 'layouts/main-html', //template to Send Emails Html based
            'textLayout' => 'layouts/main-text', //template to Send Emails text based
            'messageConfig' => [
               'charset' => 'UTF-8',
               'from' => ['ok@namesilo.com' => 'OK Premiun Clients'],
             ], //end of messageConfig
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'ok@gmail.com',
            'password' => "password",
            'port' => '465',
            'encryption' => 'ssl',
          ],
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => $db,
        /*
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
        */
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
}//end of if else loop
```

Because the session is never reached on web.php the emails are always stored locally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 - Setting Mailer Transport parameters on runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708214/yii2-setting-mailer-transport-parameters-on-runtime)

Comment: Well not exactly the same scenario, the method SetTransport allow to set values for class, host, username, password, port and encryption properties. In my case I need to find a way to update the value of useFileTransport property.

Comment: see the answer i posted, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot Muhammad, best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do requires you to instantiate the `yii\swiftmailer\Mailer` class from within your code and set the transport by calling `setTransport()`, rather than using it via defining under the components in the config file.

I will give you an example where i will use the `smtp.gmail.com` as the host for the transport and send an email

```
public function actionTest(){

    //instantiate the mailer
    $mailer = new \yii\swiftmailer\Mailer(
        [
            'useFileTransport' => false
        ]
    );

    //set the transport params
    $mailer->setTransport(
        [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls'
        ]
    );

    //to email 
    $to = "someemail@gmail.com";

    //email subject
    $subject = "this is a test mail";

    //email body 
    $body ="Some body text for email";

    //send the email
    $mailer->compose()->setTo($to)->setFrom(
        [
            'support@site.com' => 'Site Support'
        ]
    )->setTextBody($body)->setSubject($subject)->send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is this: I did some changes using my Model Class:

```php
    public function sendMail($transport, $view, $subject, $params = []){
      //set layout params
      \Yii::$app->mailer->getView()->params['userName'] = $this->username;

      if($transport == 'local'){
        \Yii::$app->mailer->useFileTransport=true;
      }
      else{
        \Yii::$app->mailer->useFileTransport=false;
      }
      $result = \Yii::$app->mailer->compose([
          'html' => 'views/' . $view . '-html',
          'text' => 'views/' . $view . '-text',
      ], $params)->setTo([$this->email => $this->username])
          ->setSubject($subject)
          ->send();

      //reset layout params
      \Yii::$app->mailer->getView()->params['userName'] = null;
      return $result;
    } //end of sendMail
```

It helped me to simplify my web.php, it wasn't necessary to use session vars.